# Recommended Perfmon counters to measure web server performance

Tags: iis-8, perfmon, azure-web-apps

Hi there are lots of resources in general about this question (I found this useful https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.08.pulse.aspx). However I would like some more specific suggestions.

- I'm a developer and I'm not a sys-admin, but my job is moving towards that.
- We have a web server (which does a few other things) on ESXI - we're interesting in seeing whether adding an extra core provides better performance.
- It hosts an intranet app and runs a few console apps - it is Win 2012 R2
- This isn't in response to a performance issue - it's more a fun learning exercise with a clear "before" and "after"
- We're putting some things on Azure where bad performance can start to get expensive and we'd like some perfmon counters that translate to that environment

In short can someone recommend some basic perfmon counters that measure the performance of a web app in Azure and On-Prem IIS 8, so we can be a little more scientific about our approach. Cheers, Chris.